# Proper ellipsis [linguistic] for "Yes/No" questions/answers containing "do + like"

Tags: grammar, ellipses

Is it grammatically correct to say/write the following

Q: *Do you like to eat ice cream/apples...?*
A: *No, I don't like [to eat apples]./ Yes, I like [to eat apples].*

Is it necessary to include the object [in brackets] if it has been mentioned in the preceding question? And how about the main verb *to eat*, can it be omitted as well?

Comment: *like* is usually transitive, so you need to include an object.

Comment: No, you can't delete a "to" infinitive phrase under identity with a preceding one.  But you can delete a verb phrase (which follows the "to" of the infinitive phrase).  So keep the "to" in your example: "No, I don't like to."

Comment: Once you include "like", you also need to include the object. But you can just say: `Yes, I do` or `No, I don't`.

Comment: I can't imagine a native speaker saying 'Yes, I like.' It would be more natural to answer 'Yes, I do' or 'No, I don't.'

Answer (score -1):

I concur with Kris' answer; but wanted to add that the next possibility after a simple *Yes/No* is to repeat the auxiliary *do* as in:

1. Yes, I do [like to eat apples].
2. No, I don't [like to eat apples].

The reason for this is that the question is actually *do you...?*, so you'd pick this up in your answer.

For a more details explanation see "[Do vs. Does](http://www.grammar.cl/Present/Do_Does.htm)" on an English grammar site.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, everyone! :) Much appreciated! :)

Answer (score -1):

> Q: Do you like to eat ice cream/apples...?
>
> A: No, I don't like [to eat apples]./ Yes, I like [to eat apples].
>
> Is it necessary to include the object in brackets[?]

If you've already repeated a transitive verb from the question, yes.

Ice cream (like pizza) is a substance every human being likes, so that question is needless. (Even those with sensitive teeth or lactose intolerance enjoy *eating* it; they just don't appreciate the side effects.)

For the question "Do you like apples?" normal answers would have the following formats:

- No. ← *A simple negative.*
- No, I don't. ← *Replacement by a placeholder 'do'.*
- No, I don't like them. ← *Repetition of the verb* and *its object*.
- No, I hate pomes. ← *A negative with a brief explanation.*
- No, they're terrible. ← *Ditto.*
- Not really. I prefer bananas. ← *A negative with an alternative.*

> how about the main verb to eat, can it be omitted as well?

The main verb is *like*. The infinitive *to eat* acts like its noun object.

The reason you need to repeat everything (unlike, eg, in Chinese) is because English grammar understands *like* as the action and the negation *I don't like* by itself means that the speaker (impossibly) doesn't perform the action of *liking* at all for anything. S/he hates or is indifferent to everything. You sometimes see people say, e.g., *I don't try* as a way of disparaging the word or action itself: *I don't try. I do everything with my full heart.*

Similarly, *I like to eat* by itself means that the speaker enjoys the action of eating itself, without concern to what specific objects might be involved.

Comment: Any particular reason for the downvote?

Answer (score -3):

Other than *Yes* / *No*, **everything else** is optional when answer a "binary" question like this.

"Yes(, I like (eating apples))."

"No(, I don't like (eating apples))."

A slight change in wording as above might be in order. I think the gerund works better than the infinitive here.

Comment: Are you saying that "Yes, I like" would be acceptable? That sounds incomplete, I think "Yes, I like it" or "Yes, I like that" would be more proper.

Comment: @Barmar Even "Yes." would be complete in all respects, is what I said.

Comment: I agree that "Yes" by itself would be adequate. But "Yes, I like eating" seems to be talking about eating in general, not about apples.

Comment: @Barmar "Yes, I like eating." is **not** an option I suggested.

Comment: Maybe I dont understand your notation. I thought by putting (apples) in parentheses you were saying that it's optional, so you were suggesting any of these: "Yes", "Yes, I like", "Yes, I like eating", "Yes, I like eating applies".

Comment: Done. That should work.

Comment: "Yes, I like" does not seem like a natural response to me. I think the positive response should be: "Yes(, I do  (like to (eat apples)))."

Comment: @JamesRandom Yes, that´s right.